# Return full row from search

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC , I wrote C# code for search in table that search for the person name how can I store the full row to use the other information for the same person such as age, gender?

```
public ActionResult Index(string searching)
{
    var PersonTable = db.Person;
    var Name= PersonTable.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(searching.ToLower()));
    return null;   
}
```

Comment: Its not clear what your asking. You have shown us code which does not even compile (your method is not returning anything). What is the `Index.cshtml` view associated with this method?

Comment: You have shown us code which does not even compile (your method is not returning anything) yes because I want to store name then return the age for example for the same person, I don't want to return the name user search about it, you understand me?

Comment: @Rawan what you meant by _ how can I store the full row to use_ ? Also Name will be IQeryable<Person> and not single string - assuming you using entity framework.

Comment: You have already assigned a collection of `Person` to your `Name` variable (perhaps name if say `persons` which would make more sense). What do you want to do with it?

Comment: the user will search by name

Comment: Yes we know. But what do you want to do with the results of your query?

Comment: what do you want to do with the results of your query?  print the age of this person

Comment: The do it! If you cannot even be bothered to show your view, then no one can help.

Answer (score 0):

i try to explain with example, in my case i get the whole row by 'select s'

```
public void LinqTest() {

            List<Student> list1 = new List<Student> {
              new Student() {id=1,name="Ali Imran",age=25 },
              new Student() {id=1,name="Usman Ali",age=27 },
              new Student() {id=1,name="Umer Ali",age=30 },
            };

            var result = from s in list1 where s.age>27 select s ;
            foreach (Student std in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(std.id+"-"+std.name + "-" + std.age);

            }
        }
```